# Racecar image tagging

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, image-recognition

I am working on a system to simplify our image library which grows anywhere from 7k to 20k new pictures per week.  The specific application is identifying which race cars are in pictures (all cars are similar shapes with different paint schemes).  I plan to use python and tensorflow for this portion of the project.

My initial thought was to use image classification to classify the image by car; however, there is a very high probability of the picture containing multiple cars.  My next thought is to use object detection to detect the car numbers (present in fixed location on all cars [nose, tail, both doors, and roof] and consistent font week to week).  Lastly there is the approach of object recognition of the whole car. This, on the surface, seems to be the most practical; however, the paint schemes change enough that it may not be.

Which approach will give me the best results?  I have pulled a large number of images out for training, and obviously the different methods require very different training datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to use all 3 methods as an ensamble. You train all 3 of those models, and pass the input image to all 3 of them. Then, there are several ways how you can evaluate output.

1. You can sum up the probabilities for all of the classes for all 3 models and then draw a conclusion based on the highest probability.
2. You can get prediction from every model and decide based on number of votes: 1. model - class1, 2. model - class2, 3. model - class2 ==> class2
3. You can do something like weighted decision making. So, let's say that first model is the best and the most robust one but you don't trust it 100% and want to see what other models will say. Than you can weight the output of the first model with 0.6, and output of other two models with weight of 0.2.

I hope this helps :)